# How can I listen to stdout of detached unref'ed spawned child process in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, child-process

**Example 1:** the child process is detached indeed, the script exits immediately

```js
const cp = require('child_process');
const bash = cp.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', 'sleep 1 && echo Hello && sleep 3'], {
  stdio: 'ignore',
  detached: true,
});

bash.unref();
```

**Example 2:** we don't ignore `stdio`, but now the child process is not really detached as we wait all 4 seconds.

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const bash = cp.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', 'sleep 1 && echo Hello && sleep 3'], {
  detached: true,
});

bash.stdout.on('data', (e) => {
  if (e.toString('utf8').trim() === 'Hello') {
    console.log('Got message, can unsubscribe now');
    bash.unref();
  }
});
```

Is there some efficient way in Node.js to achieve the behavior as in example 1 and the logic (with listening to stdout of the spawned process) as in example 2?

Comment: You can just do `bash.unref()` right after declaring it, can't you? Why are you `unref()`'ing only after the `stdout 'data'` event?

Comment: @RafaelSofi-zada, thanks for the question. The goal was to get a confirmation from the other process it is already up and running (it prints that in stdout after a while / or an error message instead if it can't start), and only then resume the flow. After that, however, I don't want to be reffed to that process - if my process gets killed, that other one shouldn't.